# Is a factorial  an algebraic function and an elementary function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, factorial, differential-field

Following is a question spun off from [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98171/98173#comment231744_98173) I received:

> is a factorial an elementary function and an algebraic function?

From [elementary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) by Wikipedia

> By starting with the field of rational functions, two special types of transcendental extensions (the logarithm and the exponential) can be added to the field building a tower containing elementary functions.

So isn't a factorial a multiplication of finite polynomials, and therefore a polynomial, a rational function, an algebraic function, and an elementary function?

**Added**: Now I realized a factorial cannot be a polynomial, for that it doesn't make sense to talk about its degree while it does for a polynomial

Thanks!

Comment: From my perspective your question may be good, but its not phrased properly, I can't understand your main doubt, may be the question can be reformulated more neatly , but is this problem only for me ?, if so sorry !! @Tim

Comment: How a factorial is a multiplication of finite polynomials ?

Comment: @Sasha: $n!=n \times (n-1) \times \cdots \times 1$. I am not claiming it is true. I am not sure, but it seems like a multiplication of finite polynomials.

Comment: ["...in 1887 Holder proved that the gamma function is transcendentally transcendental, which incidentally gives a naturally occurring example of an infinitely differentiable function that is far more non-elementary than (the usual transcendental functions)..."](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/55016)

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks! What is that "naturally occurring example of an infinitely differentiable function that is far more non-elementary than (the usual transcendental functions)"? Are you saying it is the factorial?

Comment: The gamma function (factorial), of course. I quoted and linked to Dave's answer; you might wish to peruse the references he gave.

Comment: @Tim : your idea is very beautiful, but I need to tell sorry as sometimes humans assert something, so I never like such assertions , as I know that one man's sweet is another man's poison, If I don't understand , it doesn't mean that nobody understands it .

Comment: @Tim : Hey you took me in wrong sense, I was saying I asserted something , you understand ? , I wanted to say humans assert something, I was referring to myself ( I mean that I asserted that your question is not properly presented , but its only for me ), I never commented you, anyway lets remove these comments, I will remove my one after some time, Thanks a lot, and I apologize if I caused you any trouble

Comment: @Tim : I have edited your question, you are at liberty to roll-back at any time .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start basically factorial is really a function, and generally the Gamma function extends the factorial to the non-integer values.

To your best reference I have one beautiful article with me, let me suggest it , its [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Hasse/00029890.di021346.02p0064l.pdf). The article is by Manjul Bhargava, it has the precise information what you are looking for.

Please read it and give your feed-back.

*Edit* : After thinking much on Mr.Srivatsan's comment , I came to a conclusion that $n!$ is not a polynomial,  in fact  $n!$ grows faster than $a^n$ for any $a$. Once you go out $a$ steps, adding $1$ to $n$ multiplies $a^n$ by $a$, while it multiplies $n!$ by $a$ by (at least) $a+1$.

And to add some interesting points,

1. The falling factorial $(x)_n$ is a binomial polynomial which is defined as $$(x)_n=x(x-1)....(x-(n-1))$$ for $n\ge 0$, and it can be related to the raising factorial $(x)^n$ ( defined as $(x)^n=x(x+1)...(x+n-1)$ ) as $$(x)_n=(-1)^n(-x)^{(n)}$$
2. The usual factorial ( that OP is talking about ) can be written as $$n!=(n)_n$$ which is not a polynomial anymore.

( *Credits* : Thanks Mr.Srivatsan for letting me know the difference ) .

Thank you,

Yours truly,

Iyengar.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect: the factorial function is not a polynomial. [In fact, it grows faster than any polynomial.] I think you just assumed what the OP claimed to be true. *Added note:* I did not downvote.

Comment: @Srivatsan : I am not an expert to argue further, but a polynomial in sense I mean a function of a single variable and its a function by definition as its a product that gives an $n$-th degree polynomial of single variable .

Comment: Yes, it is of course a function of $n$ - no doubt. But it is not a polynomial: because the number of terms in the product grows unbounded.

Comment: Ok thank you sir, I have fixed it, and I came to know about the difference , Thanks a lot !! @Srivatsan

Comment: @Srivatsan: Why is "the number of terms in the product grows unbounded" not for a polynomial?

Comment: @Tim : but have you seen the article of Manjul ?

Comment: @iyengar: Thanks! I haven't completed it yet.

Comment: @Tim: A polynomial has a fixed degree, independent of its argument ($n$ in this case). The product $n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots 1$ contains $n$ terms, which is not allowed.

Comment: @iyengar "Prof" and "sir" have specific meanings; they are not titles we can add to people's names at will. It is best to avoid using such (unnecessary, in my opinion) qualifiers in a professional forum such as this.  I can understand that you only intend to display respect, but it only comes off to the rest of community as an abuse of the title. I am not a professor; so please remove it from my name. Thank you and regards,

Comment: @Srivatsan : I have fixed it sir.

Comment: @Iyengar The link to the "beautiful" article is broken :(