# represent n! In any form other than the usual multiplication I.e. 1x2x3..n

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, factorial

derive an equation to represent n! Instead of multiplying from 1 to n. One straight equation not involving factorial like the way we represent summation of r as n(n+1)/2, where r varies from 1 to n. A similar type of expression iam looking for

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n (n-1)!$. There, I only multiplied from $1$ to $n-1$... No, seriously, what are you looking for, where are your own approaches and ideas?

Comment: $n!=\Gamma (n+1)$?  You really need to give us some idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: One single straight equation not involving any factorial

Comment: So, what's wrong with $n!=\Gamma (n+1)=\int_0^{\infty}t^{n}e^{-t}dt$?

Comment: If you are looking for some easy formula to plug into your calculator, you're not going to find one (but your calculator might have a factorial function). Stirling's approximation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is a formula to approximate $n!$ when $n$ is large: $n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$. But if you want $n!$ exactly, you just have to multiply $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots n$, or get a computer to do it for you.

Comment: More simpler , solution should contain powers of n and  no integration

Comment: @Mohdatif There is no such formula.

Comment: An exact solution would be more appreciated

Comment: There is and u can derive using Euler mclaurins formula

Comment: @Mohdatif That gives you Stirling's approximation, which I posted above.

Comment: Yeah I know that's why I asked for exact equation not approximation

Comment: $n! =(1-t)^{n+1} \frac{d^n}{dt^n}(1-t)^{-1}$

Comment: No differentiation, Not that equation

Comment: @kccu not approximate equation , need an exact equation

Comment: @Mohidatif The Euler-Maclaurin formula does not lead to an exact equation, unless you allow infinite sums.  Stirling's approximation does not lead to an exact equation, unless you allow infinite sums.

Comment: even  taylor series doesnt lead exact solution unless you allow infinite terms. but we always can try to come closer to the solution

Comment: here is your solution        n! = √2π e^( (n+0.5) logn - n + 1 ⁄ (12n )  - 1 ⁄ (360 n^3 )+1 ⁄ (1260 n^5)  - 1 ⁄ (1680 n^7 )  )                                                              sorry for not formatting

Comment: @Mohdatif If you know this formula why are you asking us for it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no formula for $n!$ involving the usual arithmetic operations because $n!$ grows much faster than any rational function.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98481/is-a-factorial-an-algebraic-function-and-an-elementary-function.

Comment: There is as the kccu said above Stirling equation gives approximately, but Euler mclaurins equation gives you exact equation