# Estimates on growth of $^{n}3$

Tags: asymptotics, elementary-functions, tetration

I was dealing with a problem on tetration and am supposed to explain why this problem was challenging to me- obviously, difficulties stemmed from the amazing growth of $^{n}3$.
The question now is: Is there a way to estimate this tetration in form of "elementary" functions, as the factorial is approximated by the Stirling formula, $$\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{2{\pi}n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right).$$
Is there an elementary representation of the form $\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ for this tetration as a function of $n$?

Comment: I feared so, thanks anway- is there any more, say "tanglible" fucniton which does the trick as well?

Comment: @PeterForeman [is it?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function)

Comment: @PeterForeman The wording there is a bit unclear. One does not consider tetration as a composition of finitely many exponential functions because the **amount of compositions** is itself a function of $n$. As "amount of compositions" is not one of the listed operations, tetration is not considered elementary.

Comment: @PeterForeman You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98481/272831) for a similar discussion on why the factorial is not a polynomial (for a similar reason: factorial's degree does not exist, which is analogous to my answer).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ah yes, I was assuming the function being considered was $3^{3^{\dots^{3^x}}}$ for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By most definitions of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), the answer is no.

Every elementary $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ function in $n$ is bounded by ${}^kn$ for some natural $k$, since they are defined by a finite combination of operations and functions which are at most exponential.

As we have ${}^kn\ll{}^n3$, it follows that tetration grows faster than all elementary functions.