# When can you substitute $w!$ for $\sqrt{2\pi}(w/e)^w$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, factorial, bessel-functions, statistical-mechanics

Hi in one of Boltzmann's discussions on thermal equilibrium he performs a minimization which relies on the assumption that $$x! = \sqrt{2\pi}(x/e)^x$$ or as he states it " here $x!$ and $\sqrt{2\pi}(x/e)^x$ have the same value." $[1]$

I'm just wondering when does this hold true?

Here $x$ is the number of molecules with a given kinetic energy so I am assuming this is limited to the case for very large $x$? However I'm having difficulty verifying this by calculations as it doesn't seem to hold for $x < 100$ and adding orders of magnitude becomes hard to calculate as the computer returns Inf values as opposed to actual numeric values.

It seems to be a known mathematical fact though as Boltzmann goes on to note "So for problems involving $w!$, use of a well known approximation (See Schlömilch's Comp. S. 438) amounts to substitution of $\sqrt{2\pi}(w/e)^w$ for $w!$." $[2]$

So I'm assuming this has to do with Schlömilch's series but I'm not sure exactly how it works? any insights would be much appreciated, thanks!

$[1]$ See p.1980 Entropy, 2015, 17, [“On the Relationship between the Second Fundamental Theorem of the Mechanical Theory of Heat and Probability Calculations Regarding the Conditions for Thermal Equilibrium”](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275220813_Translation_of_Ludwig_Boltzmann%27s_Paper_On_the_Relationship_between_the_Second_Fundamental_Theorem_of_the_Mechanical_Theory_of_Heat_and_Probability_Calculations_Regarding_the_Conditions_for_Thermal_Eq)

$[2]$ Id. p.1981

Comment: Look up Stirling's formula.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: See also: [What is the purpose of stirling's approximation to a factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98171/what-is-the-purpose-of-stirlings-approximation-to-a-factorial).  It should be emphasized, it is an *approximation* and so $x!$ and $\sqrt{(2\pi x)}(x/e)^x$ (*you left the root and an $x$ out in your quote of [1]*) are not identically equal.  The one is clearly an integer when $x$ is, but it would be shocking if the other is, involving pi, e, and $\sqrt{2}$ like that... (*I don't know that it can be proven yet though that it never is... such things are notoriously hard*)

Comment: thanks so much!! At first I thought there could be a typo in the journal article but as noted below Boltzmann approximates $ln(x!)$ by $xln(x) − x + 1/2 ln(2π)$ rather than $(x + 1/2)ln(x) − x + 1/2 ln(2π)$ which accounts for the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), and it's not being stated correctly.  The actual formula is:

$$x! \approx \sqrt{2\pi x} \left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x$$

The error is less than $1\%$ for $x \ge 9$, and less than 0.1% for $x \ge 84$.

> and adding orders of magnitude becomes hard to calculate as the computer returns Inf values as opposed to actual numeric values.

This can be worked around by using logarithms.

$$\ln(x!) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln(k)$$

$$\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi x} \left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x\right) = \left(x + \frac{1}{2}\right)\ln x - x + \frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)$$

Note that the latter is asymptotically equivalent to $\int \ln x ~dx = x\ln x - x + C$.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This solved the mystery.  It turns out that Boltzmann's isn't using Stirling's approximation exactly.  "Boltzmann approximates $ln(x!)$ by $x ln(x) − x + 1/2  ln(2π)$ rather than $(x + 1/2) ln(x) − x + 1/2  ln(2π)$ as is now usual. For x >> 30 the relative difference is small." See. Id. Footnote 7.   Hence the missing $x^(1/2)$.