# Classification/types of functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

See: [Types of Functions](https://www.vitutor.com/calculus/functions/types_functions.html)

[image]

.

**Is there any other type of function left outside this classification?**

Comment: where do you classify $x^x$?

Comment: $F(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$ seems to be outside

Comment: @TitoEliatron, regarding your 1st comment: I don't know. regarding your second comment: that is an exponential function.

Comment: See this wiki page, I think you have a fair few more types to add :P https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @stackoverflow.com The first comment: $x^x=e^{x\log x}$, so it may be a mixed exp-log function.

For the second, It is the Primitive of an exponetial function, but as far as I know, it cannot be expressed by elementary functions. So I think it is NOT exponential

Comment: Hyperbolic functions $(\sinh, \cosh, \tanh)$
integer parts $[x]$

Comment: Hyperbolic functions are linear combinations of exponentials. Integer part is a Piecwise affine function.

Comment: Also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_functions?wprov=sfla1

Comment: But if you limit your question to a specific course/exam (not relevant to this site) then that classification might be sufficient, even though it is able to classify only an incredibly tiny portion of all the functions.

Comment: See [Expanded concept of elementary function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42793)

Comment: And an incredibly number of special functions. Among them standard special functions which list is never definitive. https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Comment: Also try classifying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function :)

Answer (score 1):

Continuous, discontinuous, differentiable, piecewise continuous, open, closed, compact supported, bounded, with bounded variation and many more besides all functions that have a domain or codomain other than the reals.