# Field Extensions with Common Transcendental Numbers

Tags: transcendental-numbers, galois-extensions, integral-extensions, transcendence-theory

Does anyone know if there is work done in this direction where one extends (the field) $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ with certain common transcendental numbers such as $\pi$, $e$, etc. For example, can one "get away" with such a field extension rather than the full of $\mathbb{R}$ in certain proofs? And if that is the case, are there any benefits in, for example, automatic proofs in computer algebra?

Comment: Th notion of a [transcendence-degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree) might be of interest to You.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I am familiar with trascendence-degree.

Comment: Maybe useful is [*What Is a closed-form number?*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1999.12005066) by Timothy Y. Chow (1999; [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589148) and [8 May 1998 arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9805045.pdf)), in particular his discussion of the field $\mathbb E$ of complex numbers that are closed under the operations of base-$e$-logarithm and base-$e$-exponentiation. For the type of application you're thinking of, it seems reasonable to me that the author of such a paper might cite Chow's paper (which is rather well known).

Comment: Thanks @DaveL.Renfro.

Comment: Here is another more recent paper that I found (when searching for Chow references) interesting: https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/resources/jon/closed-form.pdf Since this is an active research topic, I don't expect a clear answer here.

Comment: Here's the published version: Jonathan Michael Borwein  (1951-2016) and Richard Eugene Crandall (1947-2012), [*Closed forms: what they are and why we care*](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201301/rnoti-p50.pdf), **Notices of the American Mathematical Society** 60 #1 (January 2013), 50-65. See also [What does closed form solution usually mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9199/13130) and [these questions linked to it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/9199). And maybe my answer to [Expanded concept of elementary function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/55016/13130)