# Is there a finite set comprising the solutions to indefinite integrals of common functions?

Tags: integration, special-functions, closed-form, elementary-functions

There are some integrals that are impossible to express in terms of elementary function, for example, $ \int \frac{e^x}{x} dx $ is only expressible as a "special" function $Ei(x)$, the exponential integral, or $ \int \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = Si(x)$, the sine integral.

Is there a finite set of solutions $S$ of functions (and compositions of those functions) able to represent the set of solutions of a given finite set $C$ of functions?

What if we consider the set $S$, and ask if it is closed under indefinite integration? For example, if $C$ is the set of [elementary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), $S$ would have to include $Ei(x)$, and integrals of functions involving $Ei(x)$ and other functions in $S$ would be have to be closed under integration.

Could we iterate this process by making $S$ our new $C$, and always come up with a finite set as an answer? Will this process eventually stop producing new answers, making the set of *all* functions derivable from integrals on the set of compositions of elementary functions closed?

Comment: The set of all polynomials?

Comment: It makes a difference whether one says S is closed *only* allowing indefinite integration, or on the other hand allowing (say) products of functions in S followed by indefinite integration.

Comment: Products (or any kind of composition, since multiplication is just a binary function) would be allowed before indefinite integration, hence: "(and compositions of those functions)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sets $C$ and $S$ cannot be finite if they are closed regarding composition because composition, e.g. iterated composition, is not finite.

If your set $C$ is finite, the set of the antiderivatives is finite.

The set of the elementary functions is infinite.

The set of functions you asked for are the [Liouvillian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouvillian_function). They are defined e.g. in section 1 of [Davenport, J. H.: What Might "Understand a Function" Mean](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/What-Might-Understand-a-Function-Mean-Davenport/3b2f16e35f86d53bc75429e8431e0a453e9af3e4). In: Kauers, M.; Kerber, M., Miner, R.;  Windsteiger, W.: Towards Mechanized Mathematical Assistants. Springer, Berlin/Heidelberg, 2007, page 55-65.

There is an uncountably infinite number of elementary functions non-integrable in the elementary functions. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981/closing-up-the-elementary-functions-under-integration).

In the answer to [Why can't we define more elementary functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836556/why-cant-we-define-more-elementary-functions/836584#836584), it is stated that the process of adding necessary new transcendents (antiderivatives) is infinite.